# PostgreSQL- How to validate two fields values ocorrence

Tags: postgresql, validation

I have a table that contains the name and date columns. I want to block the insertion of a repeated combination. For example, if I have a record with
{name: "joe", date: "2021-05-24"} I need to not allow the insertion of another record {name: "joe", date: "2021-05-24"}. Do exists a simple way to do this in PosgresSQL?

Initially I thought of a dynamic concatenator that would create a string for a column that would be responsible for this validation but I imagine that there is something more elegant.

Comment: So you want to allow joes with other dates? And other people on the same date?

Comment: @Bergi yes. I want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a multi-column [`UNIQUE` index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-unique.html) (or primary key, which uses the same thing underneath). No need for concatenation.